# Application Crashes when clicking button

Tags: java, android

Im making an android app that is crashing every time i try call another Activity. Im trying to read the log cat but i cant see where the issue is or why its crashing?

> MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SearchResults.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

> SearchResults.java

(This is the activity that is called from MainActivity.java)

```
public class SearchResults extends MainActivity {

    private String userAlias;
    private String Title;
    private String amount;
    private String currency;
    private String thumbnailImageURL;
    private String tradeSummary;

    public String getuserAlias() {
        return userAlias;
    }
    public void setuserAlias(String userAlias) {
        this.userAlias = userAlias;
    }
//    public String getTitle() {
//        return Title;
//    }
    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }
    public String getamount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setamount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getthumbnailImageURL() {
        return thumbnailImageURL;
    }
    public void setthumbnailImageURL(String thumbnailImageURL) {
        this.thumbnailImageURL = thumbnailImageURL;
    }

    public String getcurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setcurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public String gettradeSummary() {
        return tradeSummary;
    }
    public void settradeSummary(String tradeSummary) {
        this.tradeSummary = tradeSummary;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchRestuls [name=" + userAlias + ", link=" + thumbnailImageURL + ", about="
                + Title + ", imgUrl=" + thumbnailImageURL + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
    }
}
```

> LogCat results:

```
> 02-27 07:49:31.048    1623-1623/com.ryan.bobdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.ryan.bobdemo, PID: 1623
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ryan.bobdemo/com.ryan.bobdemo.SearchResults}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ryan.bobdemo.SearchResults cannot be
> cast to android.app.Activity
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ryan.bobdemo.SearchResults cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> XML Of MainActivity (As requested)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:hint="Type here"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_search" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="search_dummy"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/bob_logo_banner_sml"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is not called SearchResults

Comment: why did you post MainActivity.java's code twice. post code of SearchResults.java

Comment: also post xml file of main activity

Comment: @SukhwantSinghGrewal made the change as requested

Answer (score 2):

It says `SearchResults` does not extend `Activity`.

Since you are calling `startActivity` passing `SearchResults` to it, so your `SearchResults` should extend `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for that!!! that helped a lot!!! ok so the app is not crashing now.... but for some strange reason instead of opening SearchResults, its opening MainActivity? i have had a look over and cant see the reason for this?

Comment: made a change to the Question, had the wrong code under SearchActivity

Comment: Did you really intend to have SearchResults extend MainActivity? Aren't these supposed to be two entirely different activities within your app?

Right now, your SearchResults activity extends MainActivity but adds NO activity related code. You are just adding other kinds of methods. So of course when starting SearchResult you will run your inherited MainActivity.onCreate method.

You really should review what kind of components you need in your app, and which class is responsible for what.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SearchResults.class);
```

This line having problem , `SearchResults` doesn't extended by `Activity`.